# Скриншот фрагмента

Tags: java, android

Как сделать скриншот  фрагмента из активности?

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваш `Fragment` присоединён к какой-нибудь `View` в `Activity`, то можно получить снимок экрана примерно таким способом:

Получаем в `Activity` ту самую `View`, к которой присоединён `Fragment`:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.content);
```

Создаём `Bitmap` с нужными параметрами:

```
Bitmap viewBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
        view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
viewBmp.setDensity(view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
```

А затем рисуем на нём нашу `View`;

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(viewBmp);
view.draw(canvas);
```

В итоге у вас будет `Bitmap` - растровое изображение вашей `View`, с которым Вы сможете сделать, что захотите :)